# Jquery css selector conflict with glyphicon

Tags: jquery

```
$('#footer_action_button').text('Update').css({fontFamily:"Verdana"});
    $('.deleteContent').hide();
    $('#footer_action_button').addClass('glyphicon-check');
    $('#footer_action_button').removeClass('glyphicon-trash');
    $('.modal-title').text('Edit information');
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
```

I have that jquery function but the glyphicon doesn't display if i have the `.css({fontFamily:"Verdana"});`

i have to exclude that line inorder for the glyphicon to appear. How does it work ? But when i remove that line the font-family is ignored.

Comment: Can you add some screenshot?

Comment: @BARNI
with `.css({fontFamily:"Verdana"});`

https://gyazo.com/3857534b14c9a5706d1b81190d3eb222

but with just plain 

`('#footer_action_button').text('Update')`
https://gyazo.com/be3b8e1a2b34f4ad05f71b820dff6887

Comment: can you please also share html code so that we can understand and help in a better way

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, glyphicons don't play well with elements that include text.

Try this instead:

```
    $('#footer_action_button').append($("<span>").addClass('glyphicon-check'));
    $('#footer_action_button').children('.glyphicon-trash').remove();
```

If you want the icon before the text, use `.prepend()` instead.

or together with your code from above:

```
    $('#footer_action_button').text('Update').css({fontFamily:"V‌​erdana"});
    $('.deleteContent').hide(); 
    $('#footer_action_button').append($("<span>").addClass('glyp‌​hicon-check')); 
    $('#footer_action_button').children('.glyphicon-trash').remo‌​ve();
    $('.modal-title').text('Edit information'); 
    $('#myModal').modal('show')
```

Comment: how about the text. How can i chang the style of my text? can you please share a complete code

Comment: Just use the two lines in place of the two mentions of glyphicons in your code above. Of course this is assuming the something about how you set up the glyphicon-trash element:
        `$('#footer_action_button').text('Update').css({fontFamily:"Verdana"});`
`$('.deleteContent').hide();`
`$('#footer_action_button').append($("<span>").addClass('glyphicon-check'));`
`$('#footer_action_button').children('.glyphicon-trash').remove();`
`$('.modal-title').text('Edit information');`
`$('#myModal').modal('show');`